# How can I use newcommand/DeclareMathOperator to this?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm currently using frequently symbols like `$\widehat{\widehat{\mu(\Theta_i)}}$` or `$\widehat{\widehat{\boldsymbol{\mu}(\Theta_i)}}$`. Having a shorthand for double \widehat would be very helpful. How can I predefine this using `\newcommand` or `DeclareMathOperator`?

LOL, the code doesn't compile to LaTeX. How can I use LaTeX here correctly?

Comment: Is it always used with `\mu` (roman or bold) or could it be over any other stuff?  If it is just the hats you want shorthand for, you could use `\newcommand\wwidehat[1]{\widehat{\widehat{#1}}}`

Comment: I use it primarily with `\mu(\Theta_i)` but in many configuaration like `\widehat{\widehat{\mu_1(\Theta_i)}}`, `\widehat{\widehat{\mu_2(\Theta_i)}}` etc. so defining a new shorthand for every these combination is rather pointless.

Comment: Then I would ask if my `\wwidehat` newcommand is sufficient?  Without text associated with it, it would not be an operator, but rather an accent.

Comment: By the way, your code compiles with either the `amsmath` or `mathtools` package loaded.

Comment: @PLrc What is the use of this double hat ?

Comment: The `isomath` package allows you to use `\mathbfit{\mu}`, and `unicode-math` also gives you `\symbfit{\mu}` and `\mbfitmu`. In `unicode-math` in particular, `\boldsymbol{\mu}` will use a different symbol and not work by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parametrize the variable part.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newcommand{\bmu}{\bm{\mu}}
\newcommand{\wwmti}[1]{%
  \widehat{\widehat{#1(\Theta_i)}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\wwmti{\mu}+\wwmti{\mu_1}+\wwmti{\bmu}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the `mtpro2` package -- or, at least, its "lite" subset, it'll give you some *really wide* single-hat and double-hat "accents".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{newtxtext}    % Times Roman clone text font
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} $ Times Roman clone math font
\newcommand{\dwidehat}[1]{\widehat{\widehat{#1}}}

\begin{document}
$\dwidehat{\bm{\mu}(\Theta_i)}$, 
$\dwidehat{\mu_1(\Theta_i)}$, 
$\dwidehat{\mu_2(\Theta_i)}$
\end{document}
```